# How to stop 'observableTimer'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

How would you stop `observableTimer` having this code:

```
observableTimer(0, 5000).pipe(
      tap(() => this.showLoader()),
      switchMap(() => this.store.dispatch(new Load()))
    )
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.stopLoader();
    });
```

I need to run the timer until some condition, say I have a variable or observable in the code, so when it is `false` I want to stop the timer.

Comment: you mean you want to stop the timer after `this.store.dispatch()`?

Comment: @CozyAzure not really straight after, just by some future condition, just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just achieve the goal with with this code :

```
data: Subscription;

this.data = observableTimer(0, 5000).pipe(
      tap(() => this.showLoader()),
      switchMap(() => this.store.dispatch(new Load()))
    ).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.stopLoader();
    });
```

Then I can `ubusbscribe` by my condition

```
this.reconciliation.unsubscribe();
```

But not sure if it is the best approach. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

> say I have a variable

You can use `takeWhile`

> say I have a [...] observable

You can use `takeUntil`

---

Here's an example:

```
data$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.stopTimer$),
  //... 
)
```

When `stopTimer$` emits, any subscription to this observable will be stopped because the observable completes.

---

> then there is no way I can unsubscribe by my condition:

The problem here is that you are trying to unsubscribe from an observable, which makes no sense. You can only unsubscribe a subscription. So you could do

```
this.sub = data$.pipe(...).subscribe(...);
this.sub unsubscribe();
```

But I'd personally prefer the `takeUntil` method above as the unsubscription will be baked right into the observable itself by completing it.

Comment: I just used a `Subscription` instead `Onservable<number>` so this way I have `.unsubscribe` work. Do you think that `takeUntill` solution is better?

Comment: Yes, I do, but that's just a matter of preference. Using unsubscribe is totally fine. If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted and consider upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just let me play with that and I will come back.